# Create Graphs on Timeline card on Google Glass

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

I am trying to create graphs on timecards, which can be shown on Google Glass. Wat would be the best way to go about this? I tried using d3.js, but was unsure how to integrate the library.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Since you cannot run JavaScript inside a card on Glass, [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) probably isn't the best choice.

Seek out a graphing library that generates images. You can then attach or source those images into the timeline cards you create.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, create an image of the graph, and then add it as an attachment to the timecard? Also, does this mean it would not be possible to create dynamically changing graphs?

Comment: Try to build a graph simple app using achart engine library, and push the apk and try running it. may be its the way you can show a chart engine. As js dont support on google glass timeline card. If my method workd you can push some values from service and implement a listner in the glass and grab the values and launch the app with the value.

Answer (score 0):

This is deprecated, but could work nicely for your use case: https://developers.google.com/chart/image/

Comment: That was exactly my next question! Google charts images seems nice, but will it affect me in any way because it is deprecated? Is there any other alternative?

Comment: I want to query data from a database to graph it - can you use JSON in Google Chart Images? Also, does GAE support JFreeCharts [java.awt.*]

Comment: You would have to mold your data to the conventions of the Google Chart parameters. The details are in the documentation.

Comment: It seems Google Charts is going to be removed soon. Any other option I can use? [Any other charting library]?